# Rational number sets which grow in cardinality and a related sequence of numbers.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, rational-numbers, mobius-function

Define the collection of sets $\left\{Q_n\right\}$ as follows:
$$Q_1 = \{0\};\quad Q_2 = \left\{\frac{1}{2}\right\} \cup Q_1; \quad Q_3 = \left\{\frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3}\right\} \cup Q_2;$$
$$\left\{\frac{1}{4}, \frac{2}{4}, \frac{3}{4}\right\} \cup Q_3; \quad \left\{\frac{1}{5}, \frac{2}{5}, \frac{3}{5}, \frac{4}{5}\right\} \cup Q_4;$$
and then generally 
$$Q_n = \left\{\frac{1}{n}, \frac{2}{n}, \frac{3}{n}, \frac{4}{n}, \ldots, \frac{n-1}{n}\right\} \cup Q_{n-1}.$$
(There will of course be repeated rational numbers that, once reduced to lowest terms, will only be counted once).

Observe now that the cardinality of $Q_n$ grows more rapidly than $n$:
$$|Q_n| \leq \frac{n(n-1)}{2} + 1, \text{ so thus } |Q_n| \in \mathcal{O}(n^2).$$

However, if we account for reduction of each quotient $\frac{k}{n}$ into lowest terms, we have the stricter inequality $$|Q_n| < \frac{n(n-1)}{2} + 1$$ for values of $n$ greater than $n = 3$.

Define a sequence $\left\{q_n\right\}_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ by $q_n = \frac{|Q_n|}{n}$.

**Does the sequence $\{q_n\}$ diverge as $n$ goes to infinity?**

In other words, accounting for reduction to lowest terms, does the cardinality of $Q_n$ still grow faster than linearly for increasing $n$?

I am guessing that a strict solution will somehow involve the [Möbius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function). This will allow us to account somehow for the number of prime divisors of each integer $n$ (via inclusion and exclusion, i.e. we want to account for everything divisible by 2 and 5, but not double count those divisible by 10). But I do not know how to actually use the Möbius function to *enumerate* the number of unique rational numbers with denominator $n$.

Comment: It may help to note that $|Q_n|=\sum_{k=1}^n\varphi(k)$. And that $Q_n$ is basically a *Farey sequence*.

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence, $|Q_n|\sim 3n^2/\pi^2$.